# Unable to capture Ctrl+Alt+Arrow key event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

For some strange reasons I can't capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> key combination inside textarea. Is it some sort of system hotkey that is getting swallowed by Windows? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Any Letter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> are getting captured fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea").bind("keydown", function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        if(event.altKey && event.ctrlKey && event.which == 38) {
            console.log("ctrl+alt+up"); //never triggered
        }
    });
});
```

When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Any Letter</kbd> is pressed I see all 3 events in console. When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> is pressed I see only 2 events (for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

Any ideas?

Comment: My God. Ctrl+Alt+Arrow rotates my entire screen in the direction of the arrow key pressed. How did I not know about this awesomeness???

Comment: @MooGoo which OS? I don't see anything like that on Vista.

Comment: Vista. Though it may be something to do with the Lenovo bloatware on it.

Comment: I think ATI graphic cards had such app that allowed to rotate the screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just checked your code and everything works just fine in IE8, Firefox and Chrome.
What browser are you using?

Have you tried using [jquery hotkeys](http://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) plugin ?

Comment: I tried this in FF and Chrome under Vista. Maybe I have some app running that is capturing this hotkey...